# Excel - Duplicated Headings across sheet need to consolidate the data

Tags: excel

Data is in a long list in row 1

Column A has the Site Name and headings with the data i need are repeated as like this example:

```
        Heading 1       Heading 1      Heading 2     Heading 2
Site 1   100              90             80             70
```

Then headings repeat one another what i need is all the repeating headings to be as below format
Any ideas where to start?

```
          Heading 1    Heading 2
Site 1       Result      Result
Site 1       Result      Result
```

Comment: Instead of `Result`, could you show what exactly this result should be? Right now it makes little sense to have two rows of data for `Site 1`. Unless there is supposed to be other metadata, from a database point of view I assume you meant to sum values using a single row for `Site 1`?

Comment: Sort on header 1 (Data menu > Sort), that will bunch them together & you can delete all but one row of them.